# Find the nearest 50 items with given geo point

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, geopoints, nosql

I have integrated this java library from Amazon that handles location based queries. It will take a long and lat and make a single geopoint number from that and store it in DynamoDB which is a NoSql database.

What i need to do is query the database and get the 50 nearest locations to a given geopoint. The library has a queryRadius() method that will get all the geopoints within the given radiusInMeters, but i'm not sure how to get the closest geopoints without limiting the radius.

Here is the queryRadius(); method they give.

```
    private void queryRadius(JSONObject requestObject, PrintWriter out) throws IOException, JSONException {

GeoPoint centerPoint = new GeoPoint(requestObject.getDouble("lat"), requestObject.getDouble("lng"));
            double radiusInMeter = requestObject.getDouble("radiusInMeter");

            List<String> attributesToGet = new ArrayList<String>();
            attributesToGet.add(config.getRangeKeyAttributeName());
            attributesToGet.add(config.getGeoJsonAttributeName());

            QueryRadiusRequest queryRadiusRequest = new QueryRadiusRequest(centerPoint, radiusInMeter);
            queryRadiusRequest.getQueryRequest().setAttributesToGet(attributesToGet);
            QueryRadiusResult queryRadiusResult = geoDataManager.queryRadius(queryRadiusRequest);

            printGeoQueryResult(queryRadiusResult, out);
        }
```

I have searched High and low for answers and the best i found(i think) is an answer that is posted on the github repository for this library. Someone asked this same question on the github page. Can someone help me understand this guys answer a little more? It may be a simple solution by for some reason my poor brain is not understanding this.

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB does not work to my knowledge. Instead, look for alternatives such as CloudSearch or ElasticSearch for querying geopoint locations.

ElasticSearch will do an awesome job.